# How to avoid writing an empty row when I save a multi-header DataFrame into Excel file?

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe, header

I would like to save a multi-header DataFrame as Excel file. Following is the sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

header = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['location1','location2'],
                                     ['S1','S2','S3']],
                                    names=['loc','S'])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 6), 
                  index=['a','b','c','d','e'], 
                  columns=header)

df.to_excel('result.xlsx')
```

There are two issues in the excel file as can be seen below:

[image]

**Issue 1:**

There is an empty row under headers. Please let me know how to avoid Pandas to write / insert an empty row in the Excel file.

**Issue 2:**

I want to save DataFrame without index. However, when I set `index=False`, I get the following error:

```
 df.to_excel('result.xlsx', index=False)
```

Error:

```
NotImplementedError: Writing to Excel with MultiIndex columns and no index ('index'=False) is not yet implemented.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create 2 Dataframes - only headers and with default header and write both to same sheet with `startrow` parameter:

```
header = df.columns.to_frame(index=False)
header.loc[header['loc'].duplicated(), 'loc'] = ''
header = header.T
print (header)
             0   1   2          3   4   5
loc  location1          location2        
S           S1  S2  S3         S1  S2  S3


df1 = df.set_axis(range(len(df.columns)), axis=1)
print (df1)
          0         1         2         3         4         5
a -1.603958  1.067986  0.474493 -0.352657 -2.198830 -2.028590
b -0.989817 -0.621200  0.010686 -0.248616  1.121244  0.727779
c -0.851071 -0.593429 -1.398475  0.281235 -0.261898 -0.568850
d  1.414492 -1.309289 -0.581249 -0.718679 -0.307876  0.535318
e -2.108857 -1.870788  1.079796  0.478511  0.613011 -0.441136

with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:  
    header.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_name_1', header=False, index=False)
    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_name_1', header=False, index=False, startrow=2)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to avoid repeating column names "location1" & "location2"? (like the image that I uploaded).

Comment: @Mohammad - answer was edited, part `header`